# Meteor: Best practice for modifying document data with user data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Thanks for looking at my question. It should be easy for anyone who has used Meteor in production, I am still at the learning stage.

So my meteor setup is I have a bunch of documents with `ownedBy` _id's reflecting which user owns each document (https://github.com/rgstephens/base/tree/extendDoc is the full github, note that it is the extendDoc branch and not the master branch).

I now want to modify my API such that I can display the real name of each owner of the document. On the server side I can access this with `Meteor.users.findOne({ownedBy})` but on the client side I have discovered that I cannot do this due to Meteor security protocols (a user doesnt have access to another user's data).

So I have two options:

1. somehow modify the result of what I am publishing to include the user's real name on the server side
2. somehow push the full user data to the clientside and do the mapping of the `_id` to the real names on the clientside

what is the best practice here? I have tried both and here are my results so far:

1. I have failed here. This is very 'Node' thinking I know. I can access user data on clientside but Meteor insists that my publications must return **cursors** and not JSON objects. How do I transform JSON objects into cursors or otherwise circumvent this `publish` restriction? Google is strangely silent on this topic.

```js
    Meteor.publish('documents.listAll', function docPub() { 
       let documents = Documents.find({}).fetch();
       documents = documents.map((x) => {
         const userobject = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: x.ownedBy });
         const x2 = x;
         if (userobject) {
           x2.userobject = userobject.profile;
         }
         return x2;
       });
      return documents; //this causes error due to not being a cursor
   }
```

2. I have succeeded here but I suspect at the cost of a massive security hole. I simply modified my publish to be an array of cursors, as below:

```js
    Meteor.publish('documents.listAll', function docPub() { 
      return [Documents.find({}),
        Meteor.users.find({}),
      ];
    });
```

I would really like to do 1 because I sense there is a big security hole in 2, but please advise on how I should do it? thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you are right to not want to publish full user objects to the client. but you can certainly publish a subset of the full user object, using the "fields" on the options, which is the 2nd argument of find(). on my project, i created a "public profile" area on each user; that makes it easy to know what things about a user we can publish to other users.

there are several ways to approach getting this data to the client. you've already found one: returning multiple cursors from a publish.

in the example below, i'm returning all the documents, and a subset of all the user object who own those documents. this example assumes that the user's name, and whatever other info you decide is "public," is in a field called publicInfo that's part of the Meteor.user object:

```
Meteor.publish('documents.listAll', function() {
    let documentCursor = Documents.find({});

    let ownerIds = documentCursor.map(function(d) {
        return d.ownedBy;
    });

    let uniqueOwnerIds = _.uniq(ownerIds);

    let profileCursor = Meteor.users.find(
        {
            _id: {$in: uniqueOwnerIds}
        },
        {
            fields: {publicInfo: 1}
        });

    return [documentCursor, profileCursor];
});
```

Comment: your example here is really well done and immediately understandable by a dumbo like me. thank you! so in your case you have fleshed out what I should be doing in the case where I am doing the user data mapping clientside. I separately received another answer that might help with mapping on server side (below) and I am going to try it out. upvoting yours anyway.

Comment: marked you as the correct answer since the other route I was exploring turns up nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In the MeteorChef slack channel, @distalx responded thusly:

Hi, you are using `fetch` and `fetch` return all matching documents as an Array.
I think if you just use `find` - w/o `fetch` it will do it.

```
Meteor.publish('documents.listAll', function docPub() { 
   let cursor = Documents.find({});
   let DocsWithUserObject = cursor.filter((doc) => {
     const userobject = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: doc.ownedBy });
     if (userobject) {
       doc.userobject = userobject.profile;
       return doc
     }

   });
  return DocsWithUserObject;
}
```

I am going to try this.

Comment: didn't work. cursor object doesnt have a filter method: so i got TypeError: cursor.filter is not a function